# How can i fix strotime for the year 1800

Tags: php

I have a little trouble with strtotime, I have a date 18 july 1868 and when I record in the database, I make `$date = strtotime (18-07-1868)`. But when I appear it, I dated `('Y-m-d', $date)` but it does not show me `18-07-1868` but `13-12-1901`.

How can I fix this problem?

Thx,

Comment: Works for me: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c884add196158843434d12de5b0c65cadd17eb2a

Comment: can you post your actual code? if you used `strtotime(18-07-1868);` I think that's invalid, you'd need to wrap it in a string.

Comment: [`strtotime` will return a minus number as long as you're running PHP `5.2.6+`](http://3v4l.org/2maLV). If you're using any lower then please note that PHP 5.2 came out 2nd of November 2006 (8 years ago) and ended support on the 6th of January 2011. Over 3 years ago.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198539/php-strtotime-returning-false-for-dates-less-than-1900

Comment: it's also worth noting that strtotime returns different output depending on 32 or 64 bit system - although I don't think that's the OP's problem. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: If you're working with dates that fall outside the 32-bit range, use DateTime objects, not unix timestamps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901
> 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC.
>
> (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed
> integer.)
>
> Additionally, not all platforms support negative timestamps,
> therefore your date range may be limited to no earlier than the Unix
> epoch. This means that e.g. dates prior to Jan 1, 1970 will not work
> on Windows, some Linux distributions, and a few other operating
> systems. PHP 5.1.0 and newer versions overcome this limitation though.

So it depends on the platform you're running it on. It needs to be 64 bit to exceed the range stated in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

You are not putting a string (single quote or double quote) in `strtotime()` function...

Try This...

```
$x = strtotime('18-07-1868');
echo date('Y-m-d', $x);
```