# Why does this calendar break between the years 111 and 1753?

Tags: php, date

I have written a PHP calendar generator here, http://shodor.org/~amalani/portfolio/apprenticeship/summer/phpstuff/calendar.php , and it works, with the exception of years between 111 and 1753. I have determined that the problem is in this line

```
$first=date('w',mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1,$year));
```

Which determines the numeric representation of the first day of the month. This returns -1 for the date, so the calendar function never starts a new week.

Here is all the code

```
<?php
$date=getdate();


?>
<form action="calendar.php" method="POST">
    <input type='number' name='year' value=
    <?php if(isset($_POST['year'])){echo $_POST['year'];}else{echo $date['year'];}?>
    />
    <select name="month">

    <?php
        $m=1;
        for($x=60;$x<400;$x+=30){
            $month=jdmonthname($x,1);
            if(isset($_POST['month'])){
                $selected=($m==$_POST['month'])?"selected='selected'":"";
                echo $selected;
            }
            echo "
            <option value='$m' $selected>$month</option>";
            $m++;
        }
    ?>

    </select><br><br>
    <input type='submit'/>
</form>
<table border='1'>
<tr>
    <td>Sunday</td><td>Monday</td><td>Tuesday</td><td>Wednesday</td><td>Thursday</td><td>Friday</td><td>Saturday</td>
</tr>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['month'])){
        $year=$_POST['year'];
        $month=$_POST['month'];
        $days=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$month,$year);

        //Get the numerical representation of the first day  of the month
        $first=date('w',mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1,$year));

        //This tabs over until the appropriate day is reached in the beginning of the month
        $week=1;
        //Output the month and year
        echo date('F',mktime(0,0,0,$month))." ".    $year." Calendar";
        //Start a new week
        echo "<tr>";

        for($x=1;$x<=$days;$x++){
            $day=date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,$x,$year));
            if($week==1){
                for($y=0;$y<$first;$y++){
                    echo "<td></td>";
                }
            }
            //Starts new week
            if($day==0){
                echo "</tr><tr><td>$x</td>";
            }else{
                echo "<td>$x</td>";
            }
            $week++;

        }
        echo "</tr>";

    }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Calendar reforms. Don't attempt to use years before 1753, since various places had completely different notions about the calendar before then.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams But then why doesn't it work for <111?

Comment: I've just tried a year in the range you mentioned using the line you determined to be the problem and I don't get a valid day. It might depend on the timezone setting or maybe the PHP version.

Comment: not going to work AT all anyways. MySQL's internal timestamp is a 32bit signed int. You CANNOT represent dates before 1901-ish or after 2038-ish unless you upgrade to a 64bit version with a 64bit time_t.

Comment: @MarcB OP doesn't use MySQL anywhere

Comment: D'oh. brain fart. PHP, I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your use of mktime()

Please note the bold section from the php manual

> year
>
> The number of the year, may be a two or four digit value,
>   with values between 0-69 mapping to 2000-2069 and 70-100 to 1970-2000. On
>   systems where time_t is a 32bit signed integer, as most common today,
>   the **valid range for year is somewhere between 1901 and 2038**. However,
>   before PHP 5.1.0 this range was limited from 1970 to 2038 on some
>   systems (e.g. Windows).

You would need to remove the need for `mktime()` to fix this issue, possibly by using the OOP [Datetime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) this however has its own limitations relating to years less than 100

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449380/how-can-i-work-with-dates-before-1900-in-php) may help you further understand the issue

Comment: But does it? You may have **a** number coming back as the day but as the Gregorian calendar didn't exist until 1582 or whenever it was, who can really say that some date in year 109 was a Tuesday? Outside the range or valid years, behavior is unpredictable without a good knowledge of php internals and c datatypes to understand why it rolls around or doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Most systems (including mysql and php) work with unix timestamps. Those timestamps are integer values starting to count from 01. of january 1970. Depending on the integer size (32 bit integer for example) the available range for the calender is limited.

That explains the range described by @Anigel.