# How to handle very old dates in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

How Can we find difference between two older Gregorian dates(from 1000 to 3000 years),I tried bellow method

```
$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));
$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
printf("%d years, %d months, %d days\n", $years, $months, $days);
```

but that works only within 1970-2038,How can I handle older dates (from year 1000) using PHP?
please give me any suggestion??

(Note:I have go through method which is already given in stackoverflow, It only allow me to format dates but I can't find difference between two dates )

Comment: A quick google search gets you [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871264/using-strtotime-for-dates-before-1970)

Comment: @PatsyIssa thats useless, as its still limited to - Fri, 13 Dec 1901...  i think to do math on older dates, you will have to write the methods yourself, I don't know of any standard PHP library which will accomplish this.

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420 My bad wrong result http://stackoverflow.com/a/2449399/1401094

Comment: @Patsylssa could you please give me any overview to write custom method for dates

Comment: if any one found duplicate question please kindly first give link for solution which is already answered.....